# Exception in connection between Hibernate and SQL Server 2005

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I want to connect my java project to SQL Server 2005 database, but unfortunately I'm getting some problems.
I am using Windows Authentification (my pc name is BOURKADIXP without password) and here is my hibernate.cfg:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">azerty</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1/DBM6000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and here is the exception that I had:

```
 org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Getting database metadata
Getting database metadata
  java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
  Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
    java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
    Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    Connection refused: connect
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that tcp/ip connections is allowed in your server configuration?
If yes, check that you are using correct port number for connection.
Or if you want to connect throught named pipe, set namedPipe=true; property in the url string.

Comment: How to check if tcp/ip is allowed??

Comment: I activated tcp/ip connections and i still have the same problem

Comment: Is it able to connect on <server> 1433 through telnet?